# json.Unmarshal Ignore json string value inside a json string, dont attempt to parse it

Tags: json, string, go

I need to unmarshal a json string, but treat the 'SomeString' value as a string and not json.
The unmarshaler errors when attempting this
Not sure if this is possible. Thanks.

```
type Test struct{
    Name        string `json:"Name"`
    Description string `json:"Description"`
    SomeString  string `json:"SomeString"`
}

func main() {
    a := "{\"Name\":\"Jim\", \"Description\":\"This is a test\", \"SomeString\":\"{\"test\":{\"test\":\"i am a test\"}}\" }"

    var test Test

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(a), &test)
    if err !=nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(a)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", test)
}
```

Comment: "The unmarshaler errors" -- What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is not a valid JSON. See this part:

```
\"SomeString\":\"{\"test
```

There's a key `SomeString` and it has a value: `{\`. The 2nd quote inside its *supposed* value closes it. The subsequent characters `test` are not part of `SomeString`'s value, they appear "alone", but if they would be the name of the next property, it would have to be quoted. So you get the error `invalid character 't' after object key:value pair`.

It's possible of course to have a JSON string as the value and it's not parsed, but the input must be valid JSON.

For example, using a raw string literal:

```
a := `{"Name":"Jim", "Description":"This is a test", "SomeString":"{\"test\":{\"test\":\"i am a test\"}}" }`
```

Using this input, the output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lQVq2YkItv6)):

```
{"Name":"Jim", "Description":"This is a test", "SomeString":"{\"test\":{\"test\":\"i am a test\"}}" }
{Name:Jim Description:This is a test SomeString:{"test":{"test":"i am a test"}}}
```

This works as intended, your problem is how you specify your input. `""` is already an interpreted (Go) literal, and you want another, JSON escaped string inside it. In that case you'd have to escape twice!

Like this:

```
a := "{\"Name\":\"Jim\", \"Description\":\"This is a test\", \"SomeString\":\"{\\\"test\\\":{\\\"test\\\":\\\"i am a test\\\"}}\" }"
```

This will output the same, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8Hb6_RnoMIj).

Comment: Ok good point thanks, but what if i dont have the option to escape the SomeString value with slashes? If im given a string like a := `\`{"Name":"Jim", "Description":"This is a test", "SomeString":"{"test":{"test":"i am a test"}}" }`\`

Comment: This works as intended, your problem is how you specify your input. `""` is already an interpreted (Go) literal, and you want another, JSON escaped string inside it. In that case you'd have to escape twice! See edited answer.

Comment: The JSON in your comment above is invalid. You can't parse invalid JSON string with `encoding/json`, `encoding/json` is intended to parse **valid** JSON string.